# Unity make a missile follow a given trajectory

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im making a game where you can fire missiles at tanks. I want the missile to follow this trajectory:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABsbk.jpg

I have tried a few things but no luck. Does anyone has an idea on how I could achieve this trajectory?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what are the axis stand for in your image?

Comment: Try using `Vector3.Slerp` (there is example in API Refrenece), but you still need some calculations for center and arc angle.

Comment: @TheMri the axis stand for x = distance and y = is height.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for: *ballistics, cannon, ballistics physics, ball parabola, etc.*

Here is an example of of shooting ball at transform:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/148399/shooting-a-cannonball.html

I don't have Unity open right now, so I can't give you full code. By the way, try to change the code below for your own use and let me know in comments.

```
 function BallisticVel(target: Transform, angle: float): Vector3 {
     var dir = target.position - transform.position;  // get target direction
     var h = dir.y;  // get height difference
     dir.y = 0;  // retain only the horizontal direction
     var dist = dir.magnitude ;  // get horizontal distance
     var a = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;  // convert angle to radians
     dir.y = dist * Mathf.Tan(a);  // set dir to the elevation angle
     dist += h / Mathf.Tan(a);  // correct for small height differences
     // calculate the velocity magnitude
     var vel = Mathf.Sqrt(dist * Physics.gravity.magnitude / Mathf.Sin(2 * a));
     return vel * dir.normalized;
 }

 var myTarget: Transform;  // drag the target here
 var cannonball: GameObject;  // drag the cannonball prefab here
 var shootAngle: float = 30;  // elevation angle

 function Update(){
     if (Input.GetKeyDown("b")){  // press b to shoot
         var ball: GameObject = Instantiate(cannonball, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
         ball.rigidbody.velocity = BallisticVel(myTarget, shootAngle);
         Destroy(ball, 10);
     }
 }
```

Comment: From their diagram it would seem that the OP wants to include the effects of air resistance.

Comment: well, in that case there is a magic page on wikipedia for ballistics. The code isn't changing so much. It have to consider rigidbody's drag if you want air resist.

Comment: Even the simplest drag-inclusive case [is significantly more complex](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/rbef/v40n1/1806-1117-rbef-40-01-e1308.pdf) than the drag-less one.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog i'm not getting your point (btw i really don't think the guy want air resistance)

Comment: In vacuum the curves should be symmetric parabolas, but they are assymetric and steeper at the end, which corresponds to air resistance. The functional form for the case with air resistance is different.

Comment: Hey thx for all the responses! I don't want air resistance, the missile can just follow the trajectory by changing its position.

Comment: well, attach the code below to a gameObject in your scene and press B in play mode. see if it does what you want. If it does you have to change the logic from input to your weapon.(remember to add rigidbody, collider, ecc to your gameObject, also change rigidbody's drag attribute to 0 since you don't want air resistance)